# Pandas replace not matching substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove some substrings in a pandas dataframe. However, it does not seem to be able to find substrings even when `regex=True`

My dataframe starts out as:

```
0                     0                @VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said.
3                    -1  @VirginAmerica it's really aggressive to blast...
4                    -1  @VirginAmerica and it's a really big bad thing...
```

If I try the line `df = df.replace(r'@VirginAmerica', '', regex=True)` it does not seem to have an effect. However if I try to match an entire line such as `df = df.replace(r'@VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said.', '', regex=True)` it results in:

```
0                     0                                                   
3                    -1  @VirginAmerica it's really aggressive to blast...
4                    -1  @VirginAmerica and it's a really big bad thing...
```

Is there any way I can try, or something that I missed, to get it to match substrings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns I used `df = df.convert_dtypes()` earlier in my program and it somehow broke the regex reading in df.replace. I just removed that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since the substring you are trying to replace is at the beginning of each string, I suggest that you try to complete your statement as follows (just before @):

`df = df.replace(r'^@VirginAmerica', '', regex=True)`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to be working either.

Comment: Strange, it works in my case with the code you provided. Just in case, could you try this: `df['c'] = df['c'].str.replace(pat='@VirginAmerica', repl='', regex=True)`